# how to find which element appears the most in an sql table

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a table set in the following manner:

```
band_id | song_name
1       | rolling
2       | stomp
1       | rage
3       | atmosphere
```

and so on, how can I find out which band appears the most?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK()` window function:

```
select t.band_id
from (
  select band_id, 
    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rn
  from tablename
  group by band_id
) t
where t.rn = 1;
```

or if you don't need ties in the results:

```
select band_id
from tablename
group by band_id
order by count(*) desc limit 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWRgCxoMvARmLphY1hZeLh/2).
Results:

```
| band_id |
| ------- |
| 1       |
```